# Yocto dunfell recipe, cannot depend on hdf5

Tags: linux, cmake, yocto, hdf5, bitbake

I'm using yocto 3.1(dunfell) to create a recipe called (eeel) which depends on hdf5.

In my recipe, `hdf5` is listed in `DEPENDS`:

```
DEPENDS += " zlib protobuf protobuf-native curl asio tclap hdf5"
```

When I `bitbake eeel` (my recipe), I got this error:

```
| CMake Error at /home/concc/yocto-tegra/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/eeel/5.8-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/cmake/hdf5/hdf5-targets.cmake:219 (message):
|   The imported target "hdf5::h5diff" references the file
| 
|      "/home/concc/yocto-tegra/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/eeel/5.8-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/h5diff"
| 
|   but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
| 
|   * The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
| 
|   * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
| 
|   * The installation package was faulty and contained
| 
|      "/home/concc/yocto-tegra/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/eeel/5.8-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/cmake/hdf5/hdf5-targets.cmake"
| 
|   but not all the files it references.
| 
| Call Stack (most recent call first):
|   /home/concc/yocto-tegra/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/eeel/5.8-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/cmake/hdf5/hdf5-config.cmake:127 (include)
|   CMakeLists.txt:12 (find_package)
| 
| 
| -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

it seems that `build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/eeel/5.8-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/h5diff` is expected. I checked the folder, **`h5diff` is not there**. So I guess the error message is correct.

Then I checked `build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/eeel/5.8-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib`, libhdf5.a and libhdf5.so and other libhdf5* files are there, which is a sign of success build of hdf5?

I also checked `build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/hdf5/1.8.21-r0/image/usr/bin`, which is the output of hdf5, `h5diff` is there. so h5diff is generated.

So here is my conclusion:
hdf5 is successfully compiled, installed, its lib files are copied to my recipe's `recipe-sysroot/usr/lib`, but its executables are not copied to my `recipe-sysroot/usr/bin`.

I's not sure if it's a bug of hdf5's recipe file (http://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/123207/), or I missed something in my eeel's .bb file.

Anyway to copy the `h5diff` files into my `recipe-sysroot/usr/bin`?

Is it related to `do_prepare_recipe_sysroot` (https://docs.yoctoproject.org/singleindex.html#ref-tasks-prepare-recipe-sysroot)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binaries to be run on target are not part of the sysroot because the sysroot is only for build time dependencies and target binaries cannot be used at build time. `SYSROOT_DIRS` specifies which files/directories are installed in a sysroot (c.f. https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/variables.html#term-SYSROOT_DIRS).

If `hdf5` is supposed to be executed at build time, you'll need to `DEPENDS` on `hdf5-native` so that the binary built for the host architecture can be run at build time. `SYSROOT_DIRS_NATIVE` specifies which files/directories are installed in a sysroot-native (compiled for the host architecture; c.f. https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/variables.html#term-SYSROOT_DIRS_NATIVE). If you need to link against `hdf5` or need its binary at runtime too, you'll have both `hdf5-native` and `hdf5` in `DEPENDS`.

Comment: if I make `DEPENDS += " hdf5 hdf5-native"`, after bitbake, `h5diff` appears in my `eeel/5.8-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin` (with a **-native** suffix) but not `eeel/5.8-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin`, so the error still exists.

Comment: If `h5diff` needs to be run at build time, the path in which `eeel` look into is incorrect, so you need to change it. It is not uncommon to have to fix CMake/meson/Makefile for tools to cross-compile or use correct paths in Yocto (or any build system).